# How can I count how many addQuiz I have used and use that to get an average score?

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment to create a program to create class Student. get the name, and total quiz score, add a quiz score, and get the average quiz score.

```
public class Student
    {
        private final String name;
        private int totalQuizScore;

        public Student(String studentName, int initialScore) //Constructor Students name and total score
        {
            name = studentName;
            totalQuizScore = initialScore;
        }

        //returns the name of new Student
        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        //adds a quiz score to the total quiz scores
        public int addQuiz(int score)
        {
            totalQuizScore = totalQuizScore + score;
            return totalQuizScore;
        }

        //returns the total quiz score
        public int getTotalScore()
        {
            return totalQuizScore;
        } 


    }
```

Here is my main

```
public class StudentGrade {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Student tim = new Student("Johnson, Tim", 0); //new Student with name Tim Johnson, Initial Score of 0;

        tim.getName(); //returns name

        tim.addQuiz(9); //add quiz score of 9
        tim.addQuiz(10); //add quiz score of 10
        tim.addQuiz(10); //add quiz score of 10

        tim.getTotalScore();//returns total of all the scores


        String name = tim.getName(); //save Student name to variable name
        int totalScore = tim.getTotalScore(); //save Student total quiz scores in variable totalScore


        System.out.println(name + " " + totalScore);

    }
}
```

I need to figure an average score for the quizes added. so to do that I need to be able to count how many quizzes are added...this where I'm having some issues.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable `count` that increments every time you call `addQuiz()`;

```
private int count; //initialize to 0 in constructor
public int addQuiz(int score)
{
    totalQuizScore = totalQuizScore + score;
    ++count;
    return totalQuizScore;
}
```

Now calculating the average is a trivial matter of dividing `totalQuizScore` by `count`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to add (in `Student`) a `quizCount` and a `getQuizAverage()` method like this,

```
private final String name;
private int totalQuizScore;
private int quizCount = 0;

public int addQuiz(int score) {
  totalQuizScore += score;
  quizCount++;
  return totalQuizScore;
}

public float getQuizAverage() {
  return ((float)totalQuizScore/quizCount);
}
```